# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php while submiting through edittable

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables

I have used edittable jquery plugin:

```
<td>Name</td><td class="name" data-pk="<?php echo auth()->user()->id;?>" data-url="{{url('/edit/name')}}">{{auth()->user()->name}}</td>
```

and, `$('.name').editable();`

This route: `Route::post('/edit/name', 'EditController@name');`

And the controller:

```
 public function name(Request $request)
    {
        $update=User::find()->where(['id'=>$request->pk])->first();
        $update->name=$request->value;
        $update->update();
    }
```

But i got TokenMismatchException error: How can i pass token while using jquery x-editable plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In laravel, for post request you have to pass the csrf token value as well. Its a security mechanism provided by laravel. To remove this error, try this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

put this hidden field inside your form tag, its value is also posted when form is submitted.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf)

**For ajax:**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Comment: but, i don't have a form.

Comment: I don't know if that uses ajax. this is the plugin i have used. https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/

Comment: this worked after adding token in html meta tag.thanks.

Comment: Sounds great :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below line in form html code

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

I hope it works.

Comment: but, i don't have a form.